# How to Parse UDT data from Rockwell Tag using PYCOMM library

Tags: python, plc

I want to use Python into an Allen Bradley PLC, grab the tags, and provide me with COMPLETE list of tags, including all UDT types.  Once I have this list, the user will select which tags they want to log from the list to a database.

My only concern as of now is how to parse the data I am getting back using the PyComm library.  Here is my code:

```
from pycomm.ab_comm.clx import Driver as ClxDriver

    c = ClxDriver()

    if c.open('192.168.1.148'):

        tags = c.get_tag_list()

        value = tags[4]

        print value

    c.close()
```

Here is the console output:

```
{'instance_id': 31819, 'template_instance_id': 2336, 'tag_name': 'Auger1', 'udt': {'internal_tags': ['Running', 'Stopped', 'Faulted', 'Speed'], 'name': 'Motor_Status', 'data_type': [(0, 'BOOL', 0), (1, 'BOOL', 0), (2, 'BOOL', 0), (0, 'REAL', 4)]}, 'template': {'structure_handle': 64721, 'structure_size': 8, 'member_count': 5, 'object_definition_size': 35}, 'data_type': 'user-created', 'dim': 0, 'tag_type': 'struct'}
```

I looked through the PyComm library, and it looks like the data is formatted in this matter:

```
self._tag_list.append({'instance_id': tag['instance_id'],
                                               'tag_name':  tag['tag_name'],
                                                'dim': dimension,
                                                'tag_type': tag_type,
                                                'data_type': data_type})
```

I assume there is a lot of work to completely parse this, but for starters, here are my questions:

1) How can I separate the tag name 'Auger1' from this string?
2) How can I separate the Internal Tags  ['Running', 'Stopped', 'Faulted', 'Speed'] from this string?

Comment: What string? I see nested dictionaries used to represent a tree-like hierarchy.

Comment: Yes I just saw that as well.  Oops!  I am new to python programming.  Thanks the the response